# how to share pandas dataframe between processes to save memory

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiprocessing

I have a large csv file(around 10Gb).
I use different ipython notebooks to analyse it.(Using pd.read_csv() to load the file into dataframe in each notebook)
My problem is , every time I read the file, 10G memory is used.
I am wondering if there is a way to share dataframe data between processes so that I can optimize my memory usage.

An ideal solution would be like this:

in my server file,

```
def InitData():
   df = pd.read_csv(my.csv)
   share(df)
```

in other notebook files,

```
def loadingData():
    df = LoadingSharedData()
    result = df.sum() #something like this
```

No matter how many notebooks I create,there would be only one piece of dataframe in my memory.

Answer (score 0):

Using `pickle` is fast and efficient if you are confident that nobody will be able to interfere with the pickled files, see [security considerations](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/183966/safely-load-a-pickle-file).

```py
import pickle

with open('filename.pickle', 'wb') as file:
    pickle.dump(df, file)

with open('filename.pickle', 'rb') as file:
    df_test = pickle.load(file)
    
print(df.equals(df_test))
```

Comment: read_pickle is much faster than read_csv.However, using read_pickle in different notebooks costs the same memory as using read_csv.

Comment: I see, you want to have multiple notebooks and expect them to share memory... hmm, I don't think that's possible.